# How can I fix my Mac-Router-Mac network?

Tags: airport, data-transfer, network

My network is amazing slow, and my question is what can I do about it.

I have done the following analysis:

Transfer from MacBookPro -> Router -> Mac Mini Intel Core 1
264,3 MB = 2114, MBit in 432 seconds. == 4,89 MBPS

Transfer from MacBookPro  -> Mac Mini Intel Core 1 (Direct network)
264,3 MB = 2114, MBit in 295 seconds. == 7,16 MBPS

Transfer from MacBookPro -> Router -> MacBook Air
90,2 MB = 721,6 MBit in 147 seconds. == 4,90 MBPS

All connections via WLAN: 54 MBit/s, WPA2, WMM, autochannel.
Router is a FRITZ!Box WLAN 3170

So, the router sucks a bit performance, thats OK. Anyway as the router shows me that all clients are connected with 54 MBit/s, shouldn't the transfer time less? What can I do/check to increase my networks speed?

Christian

Comment: The single most effective speed boost you can get is to buy a modern router.  I get 11 megabytes/second from my MacBook Pro to my Time Capsule disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks closer to 802.11b than 802.11g, the speed advertised for wireless networks is confusingly not equivalent to an Ethernet cable of equivalent speed.

This guide will be informative for you:

http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/31083-smallnetbuilders-wireless-faq-the-essentials

Basically buy an [Apple Airport Extreme](http://www.apple.com/airportextreme/) to replace your current system, and try to use the 5Ghz frequencies instead of 2.4Ghz as you are probably suffering from a lot of interference.

Example setting up with existing router:

[image]

Comment: Do you know if Apple Airport Extreme can operate with an existing router (which includes the dsl modem)? I would like to avoid to buy another hardware component (the dsl modem)

Comment: Yes, [details here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=305293).

Comment: Set the Airport to bridge your current router.   This mean you only have one network and one dhcp-server

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to make sure that your wireless router is using a channel that doesn't overlap with the channels of the other wireless networks around you. The frequencies of adjacent channels (e.g., 2 and 3) overlap, which can result in interference. Lifehacker has some good tips for picking a channel [here](http://lifehacker.com/5831845/know-your-network-lesson-3-maximizing-yours-speed-performance-and-wireless-signal).

Comment: I could double my speed with another channel. No it is 9 MBPS - not perfect, but better. Thanks!